# Adding an object to another module's globals in python

Tags: python, global

I know this is very evil, but is it possible to add an object to another module's globals, something like:

```
#module dog.py
import cat
cat.globals.addVar('name','mittens')
```

and

```
#module cat.py
print name #mittens
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setattr(cat, 'name', 'mittens')
```

or

```
cat.name = 'mittens'
```

Comment: @FogleBird: Sure, but not if you don't know that "global scope" is the same as "module scope".

Comment: now that you write it, it seems so obvious I feel a little embarrassed :) but yes, it wasn't clear to me that if you define cat.name then you can access it from inside cat (though in retrospect it's obvious)

Comment: Lots of things are obvious once you know them -- if you don't know, ask!  :)